# delete text between two string in shape object vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have shape object and i want to delete in any way the text between two string.
e.g.:

```
Dim oRang As RangeSet oRang = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
Const firstWord = "father"
const secondWord = "mother"
```

I have text in oRang: "father ajgfhdgh aghdashdgsgh sdfyghudsdghkshgfy dgvssdfhyv gdfysdfv gfdsdfv  mother".

I want to delete all words between father to mother.
How can i do that?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: You can use instr() to locate the positions of your two key words, then use combinations of Left(), Right(), and/or Mid() to break the string into pieces. Then use the concatenation operator (&) to put things back together, leaving out the middle part. Look at the VBA documentation for those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about string manipulation and doesn't have anything to do with shapes for convenience I will assume the input string to be in a variable called `str` and the result to be output to the console. Adjust as necessary.

There are basically two approaches. The first uses the **built-in functions** `InStr` to search in a string and `Left` and `Mid` to retrieve parts of a string:

```
Dim firstWordLocation As Long
Dim secondWordLocation As Long

firstWordLocation = InStr(str, firstWord)
secondWordLocation = InStr(str, secondWord)
If firstWordLocation > 0 And secondWordLocation > 0 Then
    Debug.Print Left(str, firstWordLocation + Len(firstWord) - 1) & Mid(str, secondWordLocation)
End If
```

Another way to approach this is to use **regular expressions**. They are much more powerful and can perform complex string manipulations in a very compact way.
The library *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* provides a `RegExp` class that can be used as follows, (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835 for more details):

```
Dim regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

regex.Pattern = "(.*?" & firstWord & ").*?(" & secondWord & ".*)"
Debug.Print regex.Replace(str, "$1$2")
```

This replaces the input string with the content of the first and second parenthesis in `Pattern`, therefore omitting everything in between.
Be aware that the reserved characters `.*+?()[]{}^$\` must be escaped with a backslash `\` if they should occur in `firstWord` or `secondWord`.
If you have line breaks in your input string, you should have a look at https://superuser.com/q/399381.

---

If you want to place this string back in a shape and format certain parts of it using VBA, you have to use the `Character` property of the `TextRange` which represents each single text character in the shape. Now you can assign the desired format using those character objects.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff743845.aspx for more (although that documentation is for PowerPoint, I think it will also apply to Word).

Comment: Hi,

it's remove from the text(when i check in debug i can see) but not update the object in document(i can't see the change after i run the code).

Comment: Have you tried putting the result back in the shape?

Comment: I success to delete the text with the code you sugget and i put the new text: 
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = newTextShape.
but it is also delete the Design of the shape object(Design means font, Division into sections...).
I think that i need to use with find function but i don't know to do that.

Comment: I updated my answer with a paragraph on how to format single characters in a textframe of a shape. This will be quite messy and I suggest you create another queston if you need further help with format manipulation in textframes.